# how to iterate through a column vector and output the results into another column vector

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, vector

I have a large column vector that I want to iterate through and make another column vector, but I only get the final value of the loop.

```
function[c]=height(n)
[x,y]=re(0,0.09,0.02,0.1,n); 
for i=1:length(y)
    while (i) < (n-1)/2)
    c=[(y(i)-y(101-i))];
    end
end
```

how do I get c as a column vector?

Comment: You are not using your iterator to index `c`.

Comment: Did you post the whole code? A `)` is missing in the `while` statement. Also, `i` is not modified in the `while` loop (which is good being it the iterator of the outer `for` loop) this implies that the code in the `while` loop can either be not execute or executed an infinite number of times since also `n` is not modified..

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Matlab that c is a vector. One way to do it is assigning the result of the operation inside the loop to c(i).